# how to Split the pdf file in android?

Tags: android, pdf

I am working with pdfviwer in android.That pdf will download full docouments which contains 100 pages.Now i need to split single pages and show single page wise.so anbody can help me?

Comment: Please tag your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). Read this [article](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0647.html) to get you started.